# NCover Exclusion Rules

Tags: msbuild, ncover

I have a couple of questions related to NCover:

1) I'm using MSBuild to build my project. In my `.proj` file I specify exclusions like so:

```
<propertygroup> 
   <Coverageexclusions>
     <CoverageExclusion>
         <ExclusionType>Assembly</ExclusionType>
         <Pattern>/Testing.*/i</Pattern>
         <IsRegex>true</IsRegex>
     </CoverageExclusion>
   </coverageexclusions> 
</propertygroup>
```

In terms of the exclusion type, if I have a `.exe` file, would my pattern match it as well as a DLL?

2) Does NCover 2.1.0.0, support coverage inclusions (i.e. I specify one exe or dll and it only checks that one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes you only need the module name not the .exe or .dll suffix

2) Yes with the //a option you can specify the specific assemblies you want covered